# Portfolio Optimization with Monte Carlo Simulation - How to do it with Excel?

Tags: monte-carlo, modern-portfolio-theory, excel, minimum-variance, vba

If I have **three** asset classes and their historical weekly returns for five years, how can I construct a minimum variance portfolio and **an efficient frontier plot** with Excel? To do that do I have to assume the return is normally distributed?

**Update**: there's a host of tutorials to plot the frontier for two assets as long as I have a table of say 10 possible weights of one asset. But with three assets or more plotting would be challenging as I have to come up with a much bigger table for the combination of the weights of these assets. As such I was wondering if there is some kind of simulation algorithm or any techniques to make it easier.

Comment: http://lmgtfy.com/?q=minimum+variance+portfolio+excel

Comment: Hi nouveau, welcome to Quant.SE, as vonjd points out you have to show more effort to be on-topic here.

Comment: Hi Bob, sorry that I wasn't specific enough. As vonjd points out, there's a host of tutorials to plot the frontier for 2 assets as long as I have a table of say 10 possible weights of one asset. But with three assets or more plotting would be challenging as I have to come up with a much bigger table for the combination of the weights of these assets. As such I was wondering if there is some kind of simulation algorithm or any techniques to make it easier.

Comment: @nouveau: Then please edit your question accordingly and it will be considered for reopening :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the assumption in MPT is normal distribution for returns.

You can programme yourself in R or Excel, following elementary linear algebra.

Eric Zivot (U Wash) has a spreadsheet solution here:

- https://faculty.washington.edu/ezivot/econ424/solverex.pdf
- https://faculty.washington.edu/ezivot/econ424/Efficient%20Portfolios%20in%20Excel%20Using%20the%20Solver%20and%20Matrix%20Algebra.pdf